apply_async() and get() method makes program execution slower than in one thread
I'm newbie in multiprocessing in python and trying to parallelize the calculation and filling of a three-dimensional array (M-map) with results in create_M_map() function. But parallelizing only makes execution slower...
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

from math import *

def _get_H_vector(cart_basis, h, k, l):
    H_vector = (h*np.cross(cart_basis[1], cart_basis[2]) + k*np.cross(cart_basis[2], cart_basis[0]) + l*np.cross(cart_basis[0], cart_basis[1]))
    return np.array(H_vector) # Returns vector as [x, y, z] in cartesian basis

def create_M_map(cart_basis, hkl_max):
    # Pre-allocate memory for speed
    new_M_map = np.empty((2*hkl_max[0]+1, 2*hkl_max[1]+1, 2*hkl_max[2]+1), dtype=list)

    # Avoiding nested Loops
    loop_grid = np.array(np.meshgrid(range(2*hkl_max[0]+1), range(2*hkl_max[1]+1), range(2*hkl_max[2]+1))).T.reshape(-1, 3)

    start = time.perf_counter()

    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        for hkl in loop_grid:
            h, k, l = hkl
            new_M_map[h][k][l] = pool.apply_async(_get_H_vector, (cart_basis, h, k, l,)).get()

    finish = time.perf_counter()
    print(f"М-map was created in: {finish - start} seconds")
    return new_M_map

def get_basis_in_cart(a, b, c, alpha, beta, gamma):
    <...>

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Indices that determine resolution
    hkl_max = np.array([20, 20, 20])

    # Get vector matrix of affine basis in cartesian one
    cart_basis = get_basis_in_cart(9.74, 6.16, 5.47, 90, 105, 90)

    # Creating map of H-vectors
    # It is a three-dimensional array
    # And it works too slow :c
    M_map = create_M_map(cart_basis, hkl_max)

I'm interested in the next code block inside create_M_map() function:
with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    for h, k, l in loop_grid:
        new_M_map[h][k][l] = pool.apply_async(_get_H_vector, (cart_basis, h, k, l,)).get()

In this configuration it takes ~20 seconds for execution!!!
If it neccessary there're the code of get_basis_in_cart() function. It just returns 3x3 matrix of floats:
def get_basis_in_cart(a, b, c, alpha, beta, gamma):
    sin_gamma = sin(radians(gamma))
    cos_alpha = cos(radians(alpha))
    cos_beta = cos(radians(beta))
    cos_gamma = cos(radians(gamma))

    xi = sqrt(1 - cos_alpha * cos_alpha - cos_beta * cos_beta - cos_gamma * cos_gamma + 2 * cos_beta * cos_gamma * cos_alpha)

    a11 = 1 / (a * sin_gamma)
    a12 = 0
    a13 = -(cos_beta - cos_gamma * cos_alpha) / (a * xi * sin_gamma)
    a21 = -cos_gamma / (b * sin_gamma)
    a22 = 1 / b
    a23 = -(1 / (b * xi)) * (sin_gamma * cos_alpha - cos_gamma * (cos_beta - cos_gamma * cos_alpha) / sin_gamma)
    a31 = 0
    a32 = 0
    a33 = sin_gamma / (c * xi)

    a_matrix = np.array([[a11, a12, a13],
                            [a21, a22, a23],
                            [a31, a32, a33]])

    b_matrix = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
                            [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], 
                            [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
    
    cart_crys_basis = np.linalg.solve(np.transpose(a_matrix), b_matrix)
    return cart_crys_basis

Standard Python execution in one thread takes only ~3.5 seconds:
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        for h, k, l in loop_grid:
            new_M_map[h][k][l] = _get_H_vector(cart_basis, h, k, l)

Execution with only apply_async() without using .get() and, obviously, without further use of the results takes only ~0.5 seconds!
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        for h, k, l in loop_grid:
            pool.apply_async(_get_H_vector, (cart_basis, h, k, l,))

Using apply_async() first and then get()-ting gives a result of ~10 seconds:
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        for h, k, l in loop_grid:
            new_M_map_buffer[h][k][l] = pool.apply_async(_get_H_vector, (cart_basis, h, k, l,))

        for h, k, l in loop_grid:
            new_M_map[h][k][l] = new_M_map_buffer[h][k][l].get()

Is it possible to achieve the speed of work as in the clear apply_async() variant? At least apply something similar a second time and increase this time by 2 times. This will also be fast! I'm just amazed that running a large loop in one thread is the fastest way...
